# Audio file doesn't play in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I use a code for playing a .caf audio file, the same code works good in an iPhone 4s and an iPad 2 but doesn't play at all in a iPhone 5...

this is the code:

```
-(IBAction)checkSound:(id)sender
 {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Lunatic.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]]; 

NSLog(@"%@",url);

NSError *error;

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0; 

self.audioPlayer.volume = 1; 


NSLog(@"log audioplayer: %@",audioPlayer);

if (audioPlayer != nil)
{
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}


if (audioPlayer.playing == NO)
{
    NSLog(@"not playing, error: %@",error);
}


if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/0D3F5169-8DB1-4398-A09A-DB2FBADF57EF/myApp.app/Lunatic.caf"])
{
    NSLog(@"file exist");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"file doesn't exist");
}


 }
```

and this is the log output:

> 2013-08-07 20:05:52.694 myApp[7006:907] file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/0D3F5169-8DB1-4398-A09A-DB2FBADF57EF/myApp.app/Lunatic.caf
>   2013-08-07 20:05:52.697 myApp[7006:907] log audioplayer: (null)
>   2013-08-07 20:05:52.701 myApp[7006:907] not playing, error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"
>   2013-08-07 20:05:52.703 myApp[7006:907] file doesn't exist

As you can see the audioplayer log gives "null" and the error log says error -43....
but I repeat... with iphone 4s everything works good....

Any clue why is this happening? Did they change something with audio in iPhone 5? Could it be a setting in my iPhone 5 that's preventing the sound to play? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you called `[audioPlayer prepareToPlay]` prior to calling play? Also have you double checked the audioRoutes to ensure it is playing out of the proper channel?

Two good sanity checks are to:

1.) Call `[audioPlayer isPlaying]` and see if it returns yes or no after you call play.

2.) Set the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` and wait for the callback on `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:` and see if it gets called after the length of your audio.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

EDIT:
Since you're file actually isn't playing, that most likely means you have something wrong with the path you're calling.

Print out your path with an NSLog and also check to see if the file actually exists using:

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:yourPath])
{

}
```

Comment: I tryed to add [audioPlayer prepareToPlay]; before calling the audioplayer play... but nothing happens... I also added a check to see if audioplayer is playing and it says it is not... I updated the question to show you the new code...

Comment: I updated the code... still not working but there is a number of error now... check the code in the question...

Comment: Two things according to your error: your audioPlayer is nil and the file does not exist

Comment: Yes I know... but still... the file does exist and if I test on iphone 4s or ipad 2 it works perfectly... this is happening only when I test on iPhone 5

Comment: Print out the paths on all the devices and compare then. The paths are different

Comment: Ok I have 2 different paths on iphone 5 and iphone 4s... and also I noticed that there is something wrong with the check with filemanager as it says that files does't exist in 4s too... but there it works... anyway... now I should find out why the iphone 5 path is wrong... any clue?

Comment: Ok I resolved... for some reason I had to check "Target Membership" on the caf file... 
Thanks a lot for your help and your time... I appreciate it!
Peace Massy